How to create a MSBuild target that runs when any file under 2 specific folders have changed
Context
I have two input folders - A and B.
I have an output folder - C.
There is a target that takes files from A and B and creates a set of files based on the inputs in directory C.  There is no relationship between the number of files in C and anything in A and B.
What do I want?
Whenever any file is changed in these folders A and B, I want to run a specific Target.
In other words, when C goes out of sync with A and B, I need to run the target.  Else, I don't have to run the target.
Seems simple right?
I have tried multiple suggestions from different sources and couldn't get it right.

You want some file or files that MSBuild can compare against. e.g. If example.in is produced from example.out, then when example.in is newer than example.out the target that creates example.out should be run (because example.out is out of date). When there is no relationship between files, you can create a sentinel file. A sentinel file is created or Touched when the target is run and is used as the "output". When the input files are newer than the sentinel file, the target needs to be run.

See the documentation "Build incrementally".
From the description in the question: When either folder A or folder B have new or changed files, a process needs to be run to create or regenerate the set of outputs in folder C. The files in folders A and B do not map to files in folder C.
When there is no mappable relationship between files, you can create a sentinel file. A sentinel file is created or Touched when the target is run and is used as the "output". When the input files are newer than the sentinel file, the target needs to be run.
An example:
<Project>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <SentinelFileName>lastrun.txt</SentinelFileName>
        <SentinelFilePath>C</SentinelFilePath>
        <SentinelFile>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SentinelFilePath), $(SentinelFileName)))</SentinelFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="SentinelExample" Inputs="@(SrcFiles)" Outputs="C\$(SentinelFileName)" DependsOnTargets="DefineSrcFiles" >
        <Message Text="performing SentinelExample target" />
        <MakeDir Directories="$(SentinelFilePath)" />
        <Touch Files="$(SentinelFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="DefineSrcFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
            <SrcFiles Remove="**\*.*" />
            <SrcFiles Include="A\*.*" />
            <SrcFiles Include="B\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>

Note that the definition of the SrcFiles ItemGroup is delayed until the DefineSrcFiles target runs. This is important if there are other targets that change the content of folders A and B.
To see the example work:

Create a file with the example code. (I named my file sentinel.proj.)
Create folders A and B and create some files in the folders.
Run the example code, e.g. msbuild sentinel.proj.

The message performing SentinelExample target should be dsiplayed, the folder C should be created, and the file lastrun.txt should be created.


Run the example code again.

The message Skipping target "SentinelExample" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files. shoudl be dsiplayed.


Add or change a file in either folder A or B and then run the example code again.

The message performing SentinelExample target should be displayed, and the timestamp of the lastrun.txt file should change.



Deleting the lastrun.txt file will cause the target to be run.
File deletions in either folder A or B will not cause the target to be run. This is a limitation of the Inputs and Outputs attributes.
